# Raise Integers to negative integer powers in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm having a really hard time translating this Matlab code to Python.

I'll show you my effort so far.

This is the matlab code

`Sigma=BW1/(2*(2*(-log(10^(att_bw/10)))^(1/Order))^(1/2))`

Now I tried to used Python power operator as I studied earlier this morning `**`

My code is

```
BW1 = np.array([100])
att_bw = np.array([-3])
Order = np.array([1])
Sigma = BW1/(2*(2*(-np.log(10**(att_bw[0]/10)))**(1/Order))**(1/2))
```

However it says that it cannot handle negative powers unfortunately

The result for sigma should be `42.539`

EDIT: it seems my code runs perfectly fine in Python 3. However I'm stuck with Python 2.7. So is there any easy way to port it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo BW instead of BW1 it's a typo. I have negative power. att_bw is -3

Comment: might be worth exploiting some math identities as well; e.g. `np.log(10**x)` is `np.log(10)*x` but won't over- or under-flow

Comment: @TedLyngmo can you please add the answer here as a comment? I'd greatly appreciate it

Comment: I don't understand how my code is working for you. I get ValueError: Integers to negative integer powers are not allowed. Because at one point I'm raising something to att_btw[0] which is -3 and a negative number, which in turn cause the program to fail

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.18. Could that be the cause?

Comment: Is there any other way to do it since I cannot upgrade to Python 3?

Comment: @TedLyngmo so the mistery is solved! It was a Python version issue then. Didn't know different Python version tags were required, my bad!

Comment: @claw91 Easy thing to miss :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python2 you need to make sure you use floating point numbers. To make them so, add `.` after each integer you now have in your formula.

Like this:

```
import numpy as np

BW1 = np.array([100])
att_bw = np.array([-3])
Order = np.array([1])
Sigma = BW1/(2.*(2.*(-np.log(10.**(att_bw[0]/10.)))**(1./Order))**(1./2.))
print Sigma
```

Output

```
[42.53892736]
```